# QAbstractFormBuilder Class not found in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer

I want to use the QAbstractFormBuilder class to load and safe my QWidget to a file. Unfortunately I am not able to include the class to my header or .cpp file.

It never accured with a different class before.

Does anyone know what to to do?

It is officially listed in 5.11 classes: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractformbuilder.html

Comment: show your .pro, there you must add `QT += designer`

Comment: Oh man... Thx so much @eyllanesc that of course fixed it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractformbuilder.html) is very clear as we see in the following image:

[image]

In the notes points out that to use that submodule you must add `QT += designer` in the .pro